# Getting wrong argument value when trying to call a subroutine using PackageName::ModuleName->subroutine("xyz")in perl

Tags: perl

When trying to call a subroutine (defined in a user defined module) in other perl file, getting wrong argument value

```
#moduleName.pm

package PackageName::moduleName;
use strict;
use warnings;
use base 'Exporter';

sub callMe{
    my($readArg)=(@_);
    print $readArg;
 }


#test.pl

use strict;
use warnings;
use FindBin;                 # locate this script
use lib 'path to parent directory';  # use the parent directory
use PackageName::moduleName;

if( my $temp=PackageName::moduleName->callMe("test")){
    print" True : $temp\n";
}
```

The function prints value of $temp as  : PackageName::moduleName

Not able to figure out why.

P.S. I have to maintain same convention while calling the subroutine

Comment: Your naming is a bit unlucky. The name of your _package_ is everything after the `package` keyword. The name of the _module_ usually is the same. All parts of the package name but the right-most part are commonly referred to as _namespace_ when talking about CPAN. There is a `Data` namespace that has several different modules in it, like `Data::Dumper`, `Data::Printer` and `Data::Dump`.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling a function as a class method with `Foo::Bar->frobnicate(@args)`. In that case, Perl will do the following things because of the arrow `->`:

- check what's on the left of the arrow

  - if it's `blessed`, find the package (e.g. `$q` is package `CGI`)
  - if it's not blessed, assume it's a package (e.g. `Foo::Bar`)
- within that package namespace, find a sub with the name on the right of the arrow (e.g. `frobnicate`)
- call that sub and pass what's on the left of the arrow as the **first argument**

Now it looks like this:

```
Foo::Bar::frobnicate('Foo::Bar', @args);
```

In frobnicate, you have to deal with that:

```
sub frobnicate {
  my ($class, @args) = @_;
  # ...
}
```

That's typically done in a `new`, which is the most likely use of a *class method*.

If you don't want to deal with it, call the sub directly in its namespace, and not with the arrow notation.

```
my $rv = Foo::Bar::frobnicate(@args);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way you're calling it via `->`.

When you do this, perl passes extra arguments, so you can make a constructor (`new`).

E.g.

```
 my $thing = Package::Module -> new();
```

The first argument passed is the class, so you can use that for a `bless`. See:
[`perlootut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html)

E.g.

```
sub new { 
    my ( $class, @args ) = @_;
    my $self = {};
    bless ( $self, $class ); 
}
```

This also applies when you call an instantiated object:

```
$thing -> do_something();
```

It passes a reference to `$self` as the first argument.

```
sub do_something { 
    my ( $self, @args ) = @_;
    print "Got args of @args\n";
    $self -> {firstarg} = shift ( @args ); 
}
```

If you want to do that, try instead:

```
PackageName::ModuleName::callMe("test");
```